# Why connecting the WAN port and a LAN port of a router?

Tags: networking, router, lan, wan

In [this post (in Chinese)](https://www.zhihu.com/question/30584853), there's a configuration that I don't understand: they connect the WAN port and a LAN port of the same router by a cable, and connect the cable which furnishes the Internet to a LAN port.

I know that there are LAN-to-LAN and LAN-to-WAN connections, and that the LAN ports, along with the AP, are bridged. I don't understand what happens when the WAN port and a LAN port is connected. What happens if a packet is transfered in/out?

Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 0):

The only probable reason for this setup (I can think of) is that only the internal switch is used, to duplicate the WAN connect. The routing part of the device will not be functioning anymore because of the most likely broadcast storm, caused by the loop.
One indication that only the switch is used would be if a second router is plugged in to another LAN port of this router.

All of which is pure speculation with so little information at hand (with my Chinese skills, none).

Comment: What happens when a second router is plugged in? To my best understanding, LAN-to-LAN connection for the device, also sets the device as a switch?

Comment: The second router's LAN port would be connected to this router's LAN switch to supply an internet connection. PCs could then be connected either on the first's or the second's LAN ports. All of the WAN handling would be done on the second router.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what's going on. To avoid confusions, let's introduce labels. The WAN of router A, denoted as WAN1A, is connected to LAN1 of router A, denoted as LAN1A, and LAN2A is connected to LAN1B of another router B, and LAN3A is connected to the Internet. If computer X is connected to LAN4A, and computer Y is connected to LAN2B, then what you mean is that, the packet sent from computer X to the Internet, goes through the path X -> (LAN4A) router A (LAN2A) -> (LAN1B) router B (LAN1B) -> (LAN2A) router A (LAN3A) -> Internet?

Comment: I'm not who is learning CS/networking, so I don't know many nomenclatures. I wonder how is this possible, I mean, how the routers transfer data in this case? Is it possible to do some settings on router A to mimic this process (in, say, openwrt)?